# How to mock System.Data.Linq.Table<MyClass>

Tags: .net, linq, unit-testing, mocking, moq

One of my base repository classes contains a method:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T, TDb> : IRepository<T>
    where T : IEntity
    where TDb : class, IDbEntity, new()
{
    protected internal abstract Table<TDb> GetTable();
    ...
}
```

I am writing unit test for derived repository class that contains implementation of mentioned method:

```
public class CmOptionRepository : 
    RepositoryBase<ICmOption, CMCoreDAL.DbData.CMOption>, ICmOptionRepository
{
    protected internal override System.Data.Linq.Table<CMCoreDAL.DbData.CMOption>
        GetTable()
    {
        return Context.CMOptions;
    }

....
}
```

Here: Context - is Linq-model of DB, CMOptions - one of the DB tables.

I want my 'GetTable()' method returning a special set of data.

I am going to mock the method:

```
        System.Data.Linq.Table<CMCoreDAL.DbData.CMOption> table = ...;
        Mock<CmOptionRepository> mockRepository =
            new Mock<CmOptionRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        mockRepository.Setup(mock => mock.GetTable()).Returns(table);
```

But don't know how to create an instance of `System.Data.Linq.Table<CMCoreDAL.DbData.CMOption>` class.

Question: how can I mock the `System.Data.Linq.Table<>`? Or probably I need to change method signature in order to avoid `System.Data.Linq.Table<>` class usage?

Please advise. Any thoughts are welcome.

P.S. I am using Moq.

Comment: have yo u found the solution to this problem yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0, `Table<T>` implements `ITable<T>` so that you should use the interface `ITable<TDb>` in the return type of `GetTable` instead of the concrete type. Then you can mock away.

In .NET 3.5 it is a little more difficult because `Table<T>` only implements `ITable` (not generic).

Comment: Jasom, you told "In .NET 3.5 it is a little more difficult". Am I correctly understand that you suggest to change class member from Table<T> to ITable? Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Jason : Can the type 'T' in ITable<T> be a concrete class? Or do I need to mock the T class as well?

Comment: You can't actually mock `Table<T>` because it's sealed. I'm not sure I understand your answer any more.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really expose `Table<T>` outside of your repository unless there is an explicit need to perform operations on the `Table<T>` instance. Instead, return `IQueryable<T>` in your repository, which is easier to mock. If you need to perform updates then you can return `ITable<T>`.

Comment: As you see, 'GetTable' method is "protected internal". Originally it was protected, and I made him "internal" to be mockable from unit-tests... Actually, I want to test implementation of 'GetOpionByName' method that uses above mentioned 'GetTable' method. I don't want to deal with DB during test and want to Mock this method. Actually, I do want to have it protected only... Guess, I need to inject data source for my repositories...

Comment: Heh, I mocked the repository data source, but it also returns DataTable<T>... and I can't implement it easily...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, here is a solution:

1. Mock data context:

   ```
   IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

   Mock<IDataContext> mockDataContext = new Mock<IDataContext>();

   container.RegisterInstance(mockDataContext.Object);

   CmOptionRepository mockRepository = new CmOptionRepository(container);
   ```
2. Mock returning table:

   ```
   Mock<System.Data.Linq.Table<CMCoreDAL.DbData.CMOption>> mockTable = new Mock<System.Data.Linq.Table<CMCoreDAL.DbData.CMOption>>();

   mockDataContext.Setup(mock => mock.CMOptions).Returns(mockTable.Object);
   ```
3. Mock 'table' object functionality:

   ```
   mockTable
       .Setup(mock => mock.Select(
            It.IsAny<Func<CMCoreDAL.DbData.CMOption, ICmOption>>()
       ))
       .Returns(options);
   ```

To be honest, I not sure if it will works, will check tomorrow, but now it is at least been compiled.

Comment: Yes,... Moq can't create a Mock for sealed class... :( this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Abstract away your data access code and use the repository pattern.

Comment: Don't you see that I do use repository pattern and its base class returns Table<>?